# Preload background image on XAML Page

Tags: c#, xaml, windows-8, windows-8.1

I'm developing a Windows 8.1 app with C# and .NET Framework 4.5.

I have a Page with an image as background:

```
</Page.Resources>

<Grid>
    <Grid.Background>
        <ImageBrush Stretch="UniformToFill" ImageSource="ms-appx:///Assets/Backgrounds/Clase.png"/>
    </Grid.Background>
```

But, I see that first appears the page and after that appears the image (it gets less than a second to load, but I can see perfectly a black background and then the image).

This is how I navigate to that page:

```
if (Frame != null)
    Frame.Navigate(typeof(QuizPage));
```

And I set the image as Content and Copy always.

How can avoid this problem? Is there anyway to preload that image?

Answer (score 1):

I don't know for sure, but I have a feeling that the `Navigate()` call might actually be waiting for a bit so smaller images show immediately, but to get an immediate navigation and make apps responsive - it quickly times out and navigates even when images are not loaded.

The [`AlternativeFrame`](https://winrtxamltoolkit.codeplex.com/SourceControl/latest#WinRTXamlToolkit/Controls/AlternativeFrame/AlternativeFrame.cs) and [`AlternativePage`](https://winrtxamltoolkit.codeplex.com/SourceControl/latest#WinRTXamlToolkit/Controls/AlternativeFrame/AlternativePage.cs) controls in WinRT XAML Toolkit are swap-in replacements for `Frame`/`Page` ones that come with the framework. Their API surface is fairly similar, but they have some additions. Among others - the `ShouldWaitForImagesToLoad` property that makes them wait for all images to load on the page being navigated to. Also there is a `Preload()` method that allows to preload the next page or pages so that when you call `Navigate()` - the next page with its images has already loaded in the background and can be shown immediately.

The page transition animations are an added bonus.